# Unexpected Error while launching DDMS on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: android, ubuntu-12.04, ddms

Getting the below error while starting DDMS first time in Ubuntu 12.04

[image]

Added the follwing lines to ~/.bashrc

```
export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/tools
export PATH=${PATH}:~/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
```

Please help me get going with DDMS on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try the below

If you are running a 64-bit distribution on your development machine, you need to install the ia32-libs package using apt-get::

Open your terminal and wonlaod using the following command

```
 apt-get install ia32-libs
```

http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html